# What happens if my dataset does not follow a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

I downloaded some data which does not follow a normal distribution. I understand that if my data is not normal, then statistical methods which assume a gaussian distribution cannot be applied on my data.

What should I do with my data? One method that I thought of was to localize the a range of data so that it assumes a gaussian distribution, and treating the rest as outliers. However, I'm not sure if this is a good idea since the outliers might in fact contain important information.

I would like to seek the advice of you all to share with me and everyone else reading this post on how you address such a problem.

Comment: what are you trying to do with your data?

Comment: Without knowing why you want to do this and why you have got the impression that normality is going to be necessary for that purpose this is going to be hard to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, CLT theorem applies and if your data set is large enough, you can use parametric tests that assume normality. Another two options would be: (a) transform the data so that it becomes normal, and (b) use nonparametric tests. They do not assume that data are normally distributed.

Comment: +1 for mentioning data transformations that I forgot to mention in my answer.

Comment: 1. You need to invoke more than just the CLT (e.g. consider the t-test; you can apply the CLT to the numerator but it also has a denominator). 2. Significance level isn't the only consideration; you might well have a test statistic that's close to normal at very large sample sizes (so the significance level will be close to the nominal level - a "valid test"), but it may well have very poor power relative to some other choice (such as a nonparametric test, a robust test or a parametric test with a more nearly suitable distributional assumption).

Comment: @Glen_b All true, but relevance depends on how you look at the question. If you look at it as an expression of a beginners fear, that whatever (s)he learned might turn useless in the real world, a discussion of when to use parametric and when to use nonparametric tests might overcomplicate things. If you look at it as a question, when to apply which test, then it is overly broad and has been closed for that rightfully.

Answer (score 0):

Real world data ist (almost?) never perfectly normal. So do not be scared. You can use nonparametrical statistics and most of the time, you can use parametric methods with non-normal data.

You did not specify, what kind of data are to be investigated with what question in mind, so I'll take the t-test as an example. Whilst normal distribution plays a role in it, due to the central limit theorem, it becomes quite insensitive against violations of normality, if your sample size is large. Large often meaning $n = 30$ or $n = 50$ for reasonable cases. Similiar for ANOVA.

In case of small samples, you are probably better off with nonparametric tests.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid about dealing with cases of non-normality. I was dealing with data regarding dog's height, for self-studying on data science.

Comment: Practical statistics tries to apply mathematical knowledge on real world data. Mathematics however usually has idealized, non-realistic assumptions. When you count apples, there will be borderline cases, where you are not shure, whether an apple is to small to be counted as an apple or a pear might look very similar to an apple and you are not shure, how to count it. There ist no sharp definition of what an apple is. However, you are still capable of counting apples. The question is not: Is this an apple in a precise definition, but rather: Is this close enough to an apple?

Comment: Very detailed explanation! I love your example. Thank you for your illustration. I have a clearer picture of the importance of normality, how it is applied, why it is not necessary to have a normal data when it can fit to other distributions, and also the choice of using non-parametric test.

Comment: See my comment under the other answer (particularly in relation to invoking the CLT, though some of the rest is relevant)